# ListPlot and ListLinePlot do not give the same results regarding the color?

Tags: plotting, color

I have this [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6d52brtn24x4dz/data.dat?dl=0) and I would like to make a colored curve. Using `LisPlot` gives the desired colored curve, but using `ListLinePlot` adds noise to the curve. Here is the code(MATHEMATICA 12):

```
colorBar1[arg_] := Blend[{Black, Cyan}, Rescale[arg, {0, 1}]]
        ListPlot[Style[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, colorBar1[#[[3]]]] & /@ Data, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01]], Axes -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.7, 1.7}, {-0.43, 0.43}}]
```

[image]

Now, using LisLinePlot gives this

```
size=Length[Data];
ListLinePlot[Data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y}, 
       colorBar1[Data[[Position[Data[[All, 1]], x][[1, 1]], 3]]]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01]], Axes -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 400, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.7, 1.7}, {-0.43, 0.43}}]
```

I don't know why the bottom branch of the curve is colored-dashed now?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `size` in the code above?

Comment: @MarcoB, code is updated. it is Length[Data]

Comment: Thank you for the update. You could write `Data[[All, 1;;2]]` then.

Comment: @HD2006 have you tried using vertexcolors?

Comment: @CATrevillian, how can I do that? do you mean redefine the color function or color bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Use [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) instead of `Position` in `ColorFunction`:

```
ListLinePlot[Data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 
   colorBar1[Data[[First@Nearest[Data[[All, ;; 2]] -> "Index", {x, y}], 3]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01]], Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.7, 1.7}, {-0.43, 0.43}}]
```

[image]

**2.** Post-process `ListLinePlot` output to add `VertexColors`:

```
ListLinePlot[Data[[All, ;; 2]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01]], Axes -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 600, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.7, 1.7}, {-0.43, 0.43}}] /. 
 Line[x_] :> Line[x, VertexColors -> (colorBar1 /@ Data[[All, 3]])]
```

[image]

**3.** `Graphics` + [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html)

```
Graphics[{Thick,
  Line[Data[[All, ;; 2]], VertexColors -> (colorBar1 /@ Data[[All, 3]])]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 600, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.7, 1.7}, {-0.43, 0.43}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh the post processing bit is awesome! I still wonder what the problem was with OP’s second plot?

Comment: @CATrevillian, for some x values  `Position[Data[[All, 1]], x][[1, 1]]` picks the rows (hence colors) associated with the top part of the curve.