# How to make interpolation for data of closed shape?

Tags: interpolation

I have a data that describes a closed shape, let here assume it is a circle

```
data1 = Table[{x, Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.01}];
data2 = Table[{-x, -Sqrt[4 - x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.010}];
Data = Join[data2, data1];
ListLinePlot[{Data}, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

the data of the circle is stored in `Data` and I would like to make `Interpolation`  so I used

```
G = Interpolation[Data];
```

but did not work and this error showed up 
[image]

Comment: how about `bsF=BSplineFunction[Data];` and then `ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t,0,1}]`?

Comment: If you want all Data points to be hit, set Option: `SplineDegree -> 1 ` ,

Comment: `Interpolation` is trying to evaluate a function, what you have is actually 2 functions (upper and lower half circles). Can you clarify what you are trying to do ?

Comment: @A.G.,  I have a data that describes a closed shape, not necessarily a circle, and I would like to use Interpolation to fill in the gaps in the data. I provided a data of a circle as an example but it can any other closed shape such as ellipse,..etc

Comment: @kglr, that is what I want. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @kglr, I have another question related to ListPlot and ListLinePlot, may you please have a look? check here  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220561/listplot-and-listlineplot-don-not-give-the-same-results-regarding-the-color

Comment: You could interpolate your x and y values separately and then use a parametric plot.

Comment: Following up on @Hugh's proposal, you can use the method in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10277) for both plane curves and space curves (under the assumption that the underlying curve is sufficiently smooth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html):

```
bsF = BSplineFunction[Data];

ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The only problem with using `BSplineFunction[]`, at least not without computations like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26898) is that the resulting curve will only pass through the endpoints.

Answer (score 4):

Below I present a way to get an `InterpolatingFunction` and a comparison of @kglr's and @Akku14's solutions:

```
Data = Join[Most@data1, data2]; (* Probably should do for BSplineFunction, too *)

gIF = Interpolation[
  MapIndexed[{(#2 - 1.)/(Length@Data - 1), #1} &, Data],
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True
  ]
```

Below one can see that the `InterpolatingFunction` and linear `BSplineFunction` pass through the data points.  One can also see that the `InterpolatingFunction` and regular `BSplineFunction` are curved instead of polygonal (no surprise). Which to use depends on the application.

```
bsF = BSplineFunction[Data]                      (* @kglr   *)
bsF1 = BSplineFunction[Data, SplineDegree -> 1]  (* @Akku14 *)

ParametricPlot[{gIF[t], bsF1[t], bsF[t]}, {t, 0, 0.01}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Red, Point@Data}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

ParametricPlot[{gIF[t], bsF1[t], bsF[t]}, {t, 0.245, 0.255}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Red, Point@Data}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: that is awesome!